# Force.com IDE for Eclipse is not working after update

Tags: ide, eclipse

i have updated force.com IDE in Eclipse since then when i try to open any class or controller i am getting following error.

[image]

when i try to create new project i am getting below error prompt.

[image]

Comment: I've updated the tags of your question for you. Please do try to find relevant tags and not use highly generic tags. Everything in this site is about salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Error clearly shows that your Force.com IDE is **not** updated correctly, there have been some errors from either in install configuration from source where this IDE updated (configuration files) or something happened during IDE update installation.

You should re-install your Force.com IDE. This error is from eclipse side.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there was an error Refreshing from Salesforce.  Try refreshing from Salesforce again.  If that doesn't work, try deleting and the re-creating the IDE Project.

Post back with your results if you still have the issue.

Comment: i have edited my post with error message i got when try to create new force.com project.

Comment: that's a really weird error.  all I can think of to do is to reinstall the Force.com IDE because it seems it's missing some plugIn to run.  The only issue I've faced with the IDE is you have to be running on some version of Java 6, else the IDE won't work.  Have you updated Java recently, say right before you encountered issues?

Answer (score 0):

Do de following steps:

1.-Open the eclipse folder and look for the eclipse.ini file.

2.-Open the file and write in the first line -clean

```
-clean
-startup
```

3.-Open Eclipse and it should work.